# Two values from range having maximum xor

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

We are given two constraint L and R(L<=R) and we have to find two values i and j(l<=i<=j<=R) such that Xor of them is maximum.

I already tried O(n^2) so want anything better.

Comment: can you share some example?

Comment: Are these values signed or unsigned?

Comment: Also, do we need to find i/j specifically, or max XOR value will be the answer?

Comment: What is n in O(n²) ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust, `n` in O(n2) is range [L...R], ie. `n = r - l`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution that you can use (This gives you answer in log(R))

Let me explain it with an example:

Let `L=34`, `R=45`. Represent them as bit-arrays:

```
L = 100010     R = 101101
```

You start from the left till you find the first mismatch of the form:

```
L[i] = 0 and R[i] = 1
```

You will always find this because L < R. (If L==R, this is trivial case and answer is `0`)

From here on, change every bit of `L` to `1` and every bit of `R` to `0`.

The numbers you get will be your `i` and `j` and their XOR will be the max you can get.

eg. 34 and 45

```
  100010 and 101101
1st mismatch at index 2 [0-based] 
From there, change all L[i] to 1 and all R[i] to 0
=> i = 100111 and j = 101000
=> i = 39 and j = 40
and i^j = 15
```

Comment: Thank you :) and sorry for no response to any questions.I had exam :)

Answer (score 1):

### If this is a one time request, with no preprocessing:

Given a range [**L**, **R**] you just need to be able to find a number that has **1** at a particular bit position among the numbers in this range. This can easily be done with bit operations.

suppose you have **L** = 0, **R** = 7, in binary your numbers are:

`000, 001, 010, ..., 111`

the current number is `000`, to maximize **xor** you need to find the number which has **1** at the most significant bit position. The first such number is **4** = **100**. Now you are dealing with range `100, 101, ..., 111` and bit at the second highest position. The bit at the second highest position is **0**, so to maximize xor you again need a number with a **1** on that position. The first such number is **6** = **110**. You can apply the very same pattern again. Now that you are done with `000` you can do the same for `001` and so on.

The number of iterations for one number is the maximum number of bits you have in numbers from **L** to **R**. Hence the total number of operations is `O((R-L+1)*log(R-L+1))`

Comment: There is no input array...its just L and R...eg. 300 and 500. Find i and j such that... `300<=i<=j<=500`, and `i^j` is max.

Comment: so your input array is `300, 301, ..., 500` ;)